# what is the uni code of map icon

Tags: html, unicode

I searched a lot about uni code of map icon symbol. But i did not find it. please any one can help me that what is the code of map icon.

[image]

Comment: Good question, I was looking for this too. I haven't found it on [utf8icons](https://www.utf8icons.com/) so unfortunately you should accept the answer below.

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226253/what-is-unicode-character-of-location

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is unicode character of location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226253/what-is-unicode-character-of-location)

Comment: I created a feature request to add this to unicode: https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-16008

Answer (score 19):

Currently (as of March 2023, Unicode v15.1 draft), there seem to be only related characters with different usual graphical representation

- U+1F4CC PUSHPIN
- U+1F4CD ROUND PUSHPIN
- U+1F588 BLACK PUSHPIN

Interestingly, there's an additional alternative *“map pin”* name in the [Unicode CLDR annotation data for the U+1F4CC](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/34/annotations/artificial.html#%F0%9F%93%8C) “pushpin” character.

More proper description of this symbol is “map marker”, as already mentioned. It might be added in some future version of Unicode, but I wasn't able to find any related proposal.

#### UPDATE

Relevant similar symbol might be

- U+1F6A9 TRIANGULAR FLAG ON POST

which is in the code charts additionally described as „location information“.

Comment: Why did they use a lollipop for the round pushpin? Couldn't they do any better? Anything closer to the asking image would do.

Comment: The "lollipop" looks more like a pushpin/drawing pin than the map marker does and therefore is better if "better" means more representative of the given description.

Answer (score 5):

I think there's no unicode character for map marker. You can use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the closest to a map symbol is  (World Map, U+1F5FA).

However, for practical usage I find the ⚐ (White flag, U+2690) or ⚑ (Black flag, U+2691) the best indicators of a place, particularly because they take the font color (i.e. aren't red).

If you don't mind red color, then Pushpin is possibly the best, as described in mykhal's answer.